# How to change startTime of time-period Dialogflow CX

Tags: system, dialogflow-cx

If I say that I want a time range of before noon tomorrow, the chatbot automatically assumes the time range is from the current time (today) until noon tomorrow. Can I edit the sys.time-period.startTime attribute to make it 5am (or something similar) so that this makes more sense?